# Postgres GROUP BY on jsonb inner field

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I am using Postgresql 9.4 and have a table `test`, with `id::int` and `content::jsonb`, as follows:

```sql
 id |     content
----+-----------------
  1 | {"a": {"b": 1}}
  2 | {"a": {"b": 1}}
  3 | {"a": {"b": 2}}
  4 | {"a": {"c": 1}}
```

How do I `GROUP BY` on an inner field in the `content` column and return each group as an array? Specifically, the results I am looking for are:

```sql
             content
---------------------------------
[{"a": {"b": 1}},{"a": {"b": 1}}]
[{"a": {"b": 2}}]
(2 rows)
```

Trying:

```sql
SELECT json_agg(content) as content FROM test GROUP BY content ->> '{a,b}';
```

Yields:

```sql
                               content
----------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"a": {"b": 1}}, {"a": {"b": 1}}, {"a": {"b": 2}}, {"a": {"c": 1}}]
(1 row)
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide the results you are looking for.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your interest! I have improved the question, my attempts, and added my desired results.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to use the `#>>` operator instead of `->>` when the right operand is a json path. Try this:

```
SELECT json_agg(content) as content FROM test GROUP BY content #>> '{a,b}';
```

Yields:

```
              content
------------------------------------
 [{"a": {"c": 1}}]
 [{"a": {"b": 2}}]
 [{"a": {"b": 1}}, {"a": {"b": 1}}]
(3 rows)
```

Comment: I assume you meant to substitute `#>>` in your answer.
`SELECT json_agg(content) as content FROM test GROUP BY content #>> '{a,b}';
              content
------------------------------------
 [{"a": {"c": 1}}]
 [{"a": {"b": 2}}]
 [{"a": {"b": 1}}, {"a": {"b": 1}}]
(3 rows)
`
This is great thanks! I will accept this as the answer

Comment: Oops, yes, I fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I think json_agg() is not the best choice to use it here, since that is concatenating the content values (the whole json data) into an array for a specific group.
It makes more sense to use something like this (and I added 'count(*)', just to have a more common scenario):

```
SELECT content #>> '{a,b}' as a_b, count(*) as count FROM test GROUP BY content #>> '{a,b}';
```