# How to group table rows based on hash present in table column

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, mysql-error-1064

I am using ahoy gem in rails application to get the analytics data which is present in ahoy_events table i want to group the rows based on the id present in hash of properties column.

Table looks like this https://s10.postimg.org/j9e5ylvuh/data_table.png

Have tried query like  Ahoy::Event.group("properties REGEXP '[{,]\"id\"[,}]' ") this returns only the first row.I know the syntax is correct but i am unable to find where i am getting wrong.Have search it a lot and tried different combination permutations of queries but could not find the correct one.Any suggesstions will be a great help.

Comment: Would it be possible to use PostgreSQL (9.4+) instead? As it supports JSON data typing you probably could find a niftier solution using it. Check this question for instance: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261409/postgres-group-by-on-jsonb-inner-field

Comment: @fabriciofreitag currently using mysql database so cant change it. is there any easy way to group rows based on hash present in table?

Comment: What version of MySQL?  Newer versions of MySQL/MariaDB have better JSON support.  Or don't hide the thing inside JSON.