# How to sum of jsonb inner field in postgres?

Tags: sql, json, postgresql, group-by

I want to sum one field **PC** value  from table test group by metal_id.

I tried this [Postgres GROUP BY on jsonb inner field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39261409/postgres-group-by-on-jsonb-inner-field)
but not worked for me as I have different JSON format

```
tbl_test

id json
1  [
    {
        "pc": "4",
        "metal_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "pc": "4",
        "metal_id": "5"
    }
]

2. [
    {
        "pc": "1",
        "metal_id": "1"
    },
    {
        "pc": "1",
        "metal_id": "2"
    },       
]
```

output I want is :(group by metal_id and sum of pc).

Thanks in advance!

```
   [
         "metal_id": 1
        {
          "pc": "5",
        }
      ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `json_array_element()` to expand the jsonb array, and then aggregate by metal id:

```
select obj ->> 'metal_id' metal_id, sum((obj ->> 'pc')::int) cnt
from mytable t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.js) j(obj)
group by obj ->> 'metal_id'
order by metal_id
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ae94a90832d952ec74160791aaaa4c5)**:

```
metal_id | cnt
:------- | --:
1        |   5
2        |   1
5        |   4
```